# FileNotFound Exception while trying to extract bean from applicationcontext.xml

Tags: java, filenotfoundexception

[This is my project structure image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qtrCt.png)

```
@Controller
public class LoginController{

    @RequestMapping(value = "/registerUser.htm", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String login(@RequestBody String userProfile){
        String message = "Hi Im here";
        try{
            ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("/WEB-INF/ApplicationContext.xml");
            UserProfile userProfile2= (UserProfile)context.getBean("userProfile") ;

            System.out.println(message);
        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());

        }

        return message;
    }
}
```

It throws an exception File not found. Please help me with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your file actually is not included in the classpath,  try putting it under src/main/ressources for example. So you can use only the file name

Comment: ClassPathXmlApplicationContext look for the configuration file in the classpath. But web-inf folder is not included in the classpath

Answer (score 0):

Try removing forward `/`

```
ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("WEB-INF/ApplicationContext.xml");
```